# Runtime Error in asp.net site?

Tags: asp.net

I developed a website in asp.net and i place the site in online. I upload my site in online by using CuteFTP. After uploading when i type my url it is giving error like this...

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's  configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

2 things:

1. In the web.config file of your app set the `<customErrors mode="Off" />`
   , reference:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx.  Doing this will show you the real, underlying error message on that page.  Make sure to re-enable custom errors when done troubleshooting
2. If your uploading using an external FTP program there are quite a few things that can go wrong -make sure all your necessary files got uploaded, make sure you application is set up as an application in IIS (http://www.affiliatewiz.com/support/appstartpoint.asp)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to see error details online change customErrors property in web.config to

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

Comment: However, you would want to eventually turn of customerrors for remote after you have fixed the problem.